# Tidymodels tune_grid: "Can't subset columns that don't exist" when not using formula

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I've put together a data preprocessing recipe for the recent coffee dataset featured on TidyTuesday. My intention is to generate a workflow, and then from there tune a hyperparameter. I'm specifically interesting in manually declaring predictors and outcomes through the various `update_role()` functions, rather than using a formula, since I have some great plans for this style of variable selection (it's a really great idea!).

The example below produces a recipe that works just fine with `prep` and `bake(coffee_test)`. It even works if I deselect the outcome column, eg. `coffee_recipe %>% bake(select(coffee_test, -cupper_points))`. However, when I run the workflow through `tune_grid` I get the errors as shown. It looks like `tune_grid` can't find the variables that don't have the "predictor" role, even though `bake` does just fine.

Now, if I instead do things the normal way with a formula and `step_rm` the variables I don't care about, then things mostly work --- I get a few warnings for rows with missing `country_of_origin` values, which I find strange since I should be imputing those. It's entirely possible I've misunderstood the purpose of roles and how to use them.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.2 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.2      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7
#> ── Conflicts ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x scales::discard() masks purrr::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()   masks stats::filter()
#> x recipes::fixed()  masks stringr::fixed()
#> x dplyr::lag()      masks stats::lag()
#> x yardstick::spec() masks readr::spec()
#> x recipes::step()   masks stats::step()

set.seed(12345)

coffee <- tidytuesdayR::tt_load(2020, week = 28)$coffee_ratings
#> --- Compiling #TidyTuesday Information for 2020-07-07 ----
#> --- There is 1 file available ---
#> --- Starting Download ---
#> 
#>  Downloading file 1 of 1: `coffee_ratings.csv`
#> --- Download complete ---
colnames(coffee)
#>  [1] "total_cup_points"      "species"               "owner"                
#>  [4] "country_of_origin"     "farm_name"             "lot_number"           
#>  [7] "mill"                  "ico_number"            "company"              
#> [10] "altitude"              "region"                "producer"             
#> [13] "number_of_bags"        "bag_weight"            "in_country_partner"   
#> [16] "harvest_year"          "grading_date"          "owner_1"              
#> [19] "variety"               "processing_method"     "aroma"                
#> [22] "flavor"                "aftertaste"            "acidity"              
#> [25] "body"                  "balance"               "uniformity"           
#> [28] "clean_cup"             "sweetness"             "cupper_points"        
#> [31] "moisture"              "category_one_defects"  "quakers"              
#> [34] "color"                 "category_two_defects"  "expiration"           
#> [37] "certification_body"    "certification_address" "certification_contact"
#> [40] "unit_of_measurement"   "altitude_low_meters"   "altitude_high_meters" 
#> [43] "altitude_mean_meters"

coffee_split <- initial_split(coffee, prop = 0.8)
coffee_train <- training(coffee_split)
coffee_test <- testing(coffee_split)

coffee_recipe <- recipe(coffee_train) %>%
  update_role(cupper_points, new_role = "outcome") %>%
  update_role(
    variety, processing_method, country_of_origin,
    aroma, flavor, aftertaste, acidity, sweetness, altitude_mean_meters,
    new_role = "predictor"
  ) %>%
  step_string2factor(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_knnimpute(
    country_of_origin, altitude_mean_meters,
    impute_with = imp_vars(
      in_country_partner, company, region, farm_name, certification_body
    )
  ) %>%
  step_unknown(variety, processing_method, new_level = "Unknown") %>%
  step_other(country_of_origin, threshold = 0.01) %>%
  step_other(processing_method, threshold = 0.10) %>%
  step_other(variety, threshold = 0.10)
coffee_recipe
#> Data Recipe
#> 
#> Inputs:
#> 
#>       role #variables
#>    outcome          1
#>  predictor          9
#> 
#>   33 variables with undeclared roles
#> 
#> Operations:
#> 
#> Factor variables from all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()
#> K-nearest neighbor imputation for country_of_origin, altitude_mean_meters
#> Unknown factor level assignment for variety, processing_method
#> Collapsing factor levels for country_of_origin
#> Collapsing factor levels for processing_method
#> Collapsing factor levels for variety

# This works just fine
coffee_recipe %>%
  prep(coffee_train) %>%
  bake(select(coffee_test, -cupper_points)) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 42
#>   total_cup_points species owner country_of_orig… farm_name lot_number mill 
#>              <dbl> <fct>   <fct> <fct>            <fct>     <fct>      <fct>
#> 1             90.6 Arabica meta… Ethiopia         metad plc <NA>       meta…
#> 2             87.9 Arabica cqi … other            <NA>      <NA>       <NA> 
#> 3             87.9 Arabica grou… United States (… <NA>      <NA>       <NA> 
#> 4             87.3 Arabica ethi… Ethiopia         <NA>      <NA>       <NA> 
#> 5             87.2 Arabica cqi … other            <NA>      <NA>       <NA> 
#> 6             86.9 Arabica ethi… Ethiopia         <NA>      <NA>       <NA> 
#> # … with 35 more variables: ico_number <fct>, company <fct>, altitude <fct>,
#> #   region <fct>, producer <fct>, number_of_bags <dbl>, bag_weight <fct>,
#> #   in_country_partner <fct>, harvest_year <fct>, grading_date <fct>,
#> #   owner_1 <fct>, variety <fct>, processing_method <fct>, aroma <dbl>,
#> #   flavor <dbl>, aftertaste <dbl>, acidity <dbl>, body <dbl>, balance <dbl>,
#> #   uniformity <dbl>, clean_cup <dbl>, sweetness <dbl>, moisture <dbl>,
#> #   category_one_defects <dbl>, quakers <dbl>, color <fct>,
#> #   category_two_defects <dbl>, expiration <fct>, certification_body <fct>,
#> #   certification_address <fct>, certification_contact <fct>,
#> #   unit_of_measurement <fct>, altitude_low_meters <dbl>,
#> #   altitude_high_meters <dbl>, altitude_mean_meters <dbl>

# Now let's try putting it into a workflow and running tune_grid
coffee_model <- rand_forest(trees = 500, mtry = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")
coffee_model
#> Random Forest Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = tune()
#>   trees = 500
#> 
#> Computational engine: ranger

coffee_workflow <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(coffee_recipe) %>% 
  add_model(coffee_model)
coffee_workflow
#> ══ Workflow ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
#> Preprocessor: Recipe
#> Model: rand_forest()
#> 
#> ── Preprocessor ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> 6 Recipe Steps
#> 
#> ● step_string2factor()
#> ● step_knnimpute()
#> ● step_unknown()
#> ● step_other()
#> ● step_other()
#> ● step_other()
#> 
#> ── Model ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Random Forest Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   mtry = tune()
#>   trees = 500
#> 
#> Computational engine: ranger

coffee_grid <- expand_grid(mtry = c(2, 5))
coffee_folds <- vfold_cv(coffee_train, v = 5)

coffee_workflow %>%
  tune_grid(
    resamples = coffee_folds,
    grid = coffee_grid
  )
#> x Fold1: model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold1: model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold2: model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold2: model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold3: model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold3: model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold4: model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold4: model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold5: model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> x Fold5: model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x...
#> Warning: All models failed in tune_grid(). See the `.notes` column.
#> Warning: This tuning result has notes. Example notes on model fitting include:
#> model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Columns `species`, `owner`, `farm_name`, `lot_number`, `mill`, etc. don't exist.
#> model 1/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Columns `species`, `owner`, `farm_name`, `lot_number`, `mill`, etc. don't exist.
#> model 2/2 (predictions): Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> x Columns `species`, `owner`, `farm_name`, `lot_number`, `mill`, etc. don't exist.
#> # Tuning results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   splits            id    .metrics .notes          
#>   <list>            <chr> <list>   <list>          
#> 1 <split [857/215]> Fold1 <NULL>   <tibble [2 × 1]>
#> 2 <split [857/215]> Fold2 <NULL>   <tibble [2 × 1]>
#> 3 <split [858/214]> Fold3 <NULL>   <tibble [2 × 1]>
#> 4 <split [858/214]> Fold4 <NULL>   <tibble [2 × 1]>
#> 5 <split [858/214]> Fold5 <NULL>   <tibble [2 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS            
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language en_AU:en                    
#>  collate  en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_AU.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Australia/Melbourne         
#>  date     2020-07-21                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version    date       lib source                            
#>  assertthat     0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  backports      1.1.8      2020-06-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  blob           1.2.1      2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  broom        * 0.7.0      2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  callr          3.4.3      2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  cellranger     1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  class          7.3-17     2020-04-26 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  cli            2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  codetools      0.2-16     2018-12-24 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  colorspace     1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  crayon         1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  curl           4.3        2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  DBI            1.1.0      2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  dbplyr         1.4.4      2020-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  desc           1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  devtools       2.3.0      2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  dials        * 0.0.8      2020-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  DiceDesign     1.8-1      2019-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  digest         0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  dplyr        * 1.0.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ellipsis       0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  evaluate       0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  fansi          0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  forcats      * 0.5.0      2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  foreach        1.5.0      2020-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  fs             1.4.1      2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  furrr          0.1.0      2018-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  future         1.17.0     2020-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  generics       0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ggplot2      * 3.3.2.9000 2020-07-10 [1] Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@a11e098)
#>  globals        0.12.5     2019-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  glue           1.4.1      2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  gower          0.2.2      2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  GPfit          1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  gtable         0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  hardhat        0.1.4      2020-07-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  haven          2.2.0      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  highr          0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  hms            0.5.3      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  htmltools      0.5.0      2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  httr           1.4.1      2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  infer        * 0.5.3      2020-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ipred          0.9-9      2019-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  iterators      1.0.12     2019-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  jsonlite       1.7.0      2020-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  knitr          1.29       2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lattice        0.20-41    2020-04-02 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lava           1.6.7      2020-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lhs            1.0.2      2020-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lifecycle      0.2.0      2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  listenv        0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  lubridate      1.7.8      2020-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  magrittr       1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  MASS           7.3-51.6   2020-04-26 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  Matrix         1.2-18     2019-11-27 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  memoise        1.1.0.9000 2020-05-09 [1] Github (hadley/memoise@4aefd9f)   
#>  modeldata    * 0.0.2      2020-06-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  modelr         0.1.6      2020-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  munsell        0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  nnet           7.3-14     2020-04-26 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  parsnip      * 0.1.2      2020-07-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pillar         1.4.6      2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgbuild       1.0.8      2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pkgload        1.1.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  plyr           1.8.6      2020-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  prettyunits    1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  pROC           1.16.2     2020-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  processx       3.4.3      2020-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  prodlim        2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ps             1.3.3      2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  purrr        * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  R6             2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  ranger         0.12.1     2020-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  Rcpp           1.0.5      2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  readr        * 1.3.1      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  readxl         1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  recipes      * 0.1.13     2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  remotes        2.1.1      2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  reprex         0.3.0      2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rlang          0.4.7      2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rmarkdown      2.3.2      2020-07-12 [1] Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@ff1b279)
#>  rpart          4.1-15     2019-04-12 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rprojroot      1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rsample      * 0.0.7      2020-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rstudioapi     0.11       2020-02-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  rvest          0.3.5      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  scales       * 1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  selectr        0.4-2      2019-11-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  sessioninfo    1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  stringi        1.4.6      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  stringr      * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  survival       3.1-12     2020-04-10 [4] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  testthat       2.3.2      2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tibble       * 3.0.3      2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidymodels   * 0.1.1      2020-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidyr        * 1.1.0      2020-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidyselect     1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidytuesdayR   1.0.1      2020-07-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tidyverse    * 1.3.0      2019-11-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  timeDate       3043.102   2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  tune         * 0.1.1      2020-07-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  usethis        1.6.1      2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  utf8           1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  vctrs          0.3.2      2020-07-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  withr          2.2.0      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  workflows    * 0.1.2      2020-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  xfun           0.15       2020-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  xml2           1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  yaml           2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#>  yardstick    * 0.0.7      2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
#> 
#> [1] /home/mdneuzerling/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0
#> [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#> [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#> [4] /usr/lib/R/library
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error here occurs because on `step_string2factor()` during tuning, the recipe starts trying to handle variables that don't have any roles, like `species` and `owner`.

Try setting the role for **all** of your nominal variables before picking out the outcomes and predictors.

```r
coffee_recipe <- recipe(coffee_train) %>%
  update_role(all_nominal(), new_role = "id") %>%      ## ADD THIS
  update_role(cupper_points, new_role = "outcome") %>%
  update_role(
    variety, processing_method, country_of_origin,
    aroma, flavor, aftertaste, acidity, sweetness, altitude_mean_meters,
    new_role = "predictor"
  ) %>%
  step_string2factor(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_knnimpute(
    country_of_origin, altitude_mean_meters,
    impute_with = imp_vars(
      in_country_partner, company, region, farm_name, certification_body
    )
  ) %>%
  step_unknown(variety, processing_method, new_level = "Unknown") %>%
  step_other(country_of_origin, threshold = 0.01) %>%
  step_other(processing_method, threshold = 0.10) %>%
  step_other(variety, threshold = 0.10)
```

After I do this, this mostly runs fine, with only some failures to impute altitude. It might be tough to impute both of those things at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much Julia! That does the trick. And thank you so much for all of the work you're putting into the `tidymodels` metapackage. Can I ask why it's a problem for `step_string2factor()` to act on variables without roles, given that It isn't an issue for `bake`? I get the impression that `tune_grid` throws out any variables without roles, and then errors later when the recipe tries to use them.

Comment: I think the main difference is that the recipes functions like `bake()` just give you back dataframes, with no awareness of roles at all, while the tune functions are role aware all the time. Having variables with no roles and then trying to select them (i.e. `all_nominal()`) causes the error. You could definitely argue that we should handle that better, so feel free to open an issue so we can track it.