# Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist when running prediction using {Tidymodels}

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes

I'm trying to predict real estate prices in R with Tidymodels. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/recipes/#recipe). All goes well until the very and when I try to run prediction on my test data.

Please see the below code example and the error at the very end.

I looked at two similar questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974520/tidymodels-problem-performing-pcr-error-cant-subset-columns-that-dont-exist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008228/tidymodels-tune-grid-cant-subset-columns-that-dont-exist-when-not-using-for)) but it seems that I have defined variable roles and provided an unprepared recipe to my workflow.

```r
    # libraries ---------------------------------------------------------------
    library(tidymodels)
    #> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.2 ──
    #> ✓ broom     0.7.3      ✓ recipes   0.1.15
    #> ✓ dials     0.0.9      ✓ rsample   0.0.8 
    #> ✓ dplyr     1.0.3      ✓ tibble    3.0.5 
    #> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.3      ✓ tidyr     1.1.2 
    #> ✓ infer     0.5.4      ✓ tune      0.1.2 
    #> ✓ modeldata 0.1.0      ✓ workflows 0.2.1 
    #> ✓ parsnip   0.1.5      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
    #> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
    #> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
    #> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
    #> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
    #> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
    #> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()
    library(data.table)
    
    library(purrr)
    
    
    # data --------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 're' means real estate
    # I'm using data.table in general. Using tribble below for cleaner data definition.
    real_estate_data <- tibble::tribble(
        ~re_id, ~price_per_sqm_huf_mil, ~district, ~num_room,
        "30876343",      0.534722222222222,        1,         3,
        "31914489",      0.476119402985075,        1,         1,
        "30972289",      0.507352941176471,        1,         2,
        "31739730",      0.472972972972973,        1,         3,
        "31783137",                0.49875,        2,         3,
        "31809435",      0.439705882352941,        2,         2,
        "31943408",      0.469117647058824,        2,         3,
        "31944348",       0.56231884057971,        2,         1,
        "31961146",      0.472972972972973,        3,         3,
        "24314388",      0.649550561797753,        3,         2,
        "29840270",      0.719178082191781,        3,         3,
        "29840429",      0.719178082191781,        3,         3,
        "30873484",      0.822857142857143,        4,         3,
        "30969673",      0.533802816901408,        4,         3,
        "31333120",      0.741511627906977,        4,         3,
        "31788730",      0.527142857142857,        4,         2,
        "31948441",      0.734848484848485,        5,         2,
        "31962350",                    0.8,        5,         3,
        "31962779",      0.670454545454545,        5,         3,
        "31979128",      0.689054054054054,        5,         1
    )
    
    real_estate_data <- as.data.table(real_estate_data) %>% .[, district := factor(district)]
    
    # train/test split --------------------------------------------------------
    set.seed(123)
    re_split <- initial_split(real_estate_data)
    re_train <- training(re_split)
    re_test  <- testing(re_split)
    
    # workflow (w/ recipe) ----------------------------------------------------
    re_rec <- recipe(re_train,
                     formula = price_per_sqm_huf_mil ~ .) %>%
        update_role(re_id, new_role = "ID") %>%
        step_center(all_numeric(), - district) %>%
        step_scale(all_predictors(), all_numeric(), - district) %>%
        step_dummy(district) %>%
        step_zv(all_predictors())
    
    summary(re_rec)
    #> # A tibble: 4 x 4
    #>   variable              type    role      source  
    #>   <chr>                 <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
    #> 1 re_id                 nominal ID        original
    #> 2 district              nominal predictor original
    #> 3 num_room              numeric predictor original
    #> 4 price_per_sqm_huf_mil numeric outcome   original
    
    lr_model <-
        linear_reg() %>%
        set_engine("lm")
    
    re_wflow <-
        workflow() %>%
        add_model(lr_model) %>%
        add_recipe(re_rec)
    
    # model training and prediction -------------------------------------------
    re_fit <-
        re_wflow %>%
        fit(data = re_train)
    
    re_pred <- predict(re_fit, re_test)
    #> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
    #> x Column `price_per_sqm_huf_mil` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you used `step_center()` to transform the **outcome** (`price_per_sqm_huf_mil`) and at prediction time, there is no outcome available. You can instead specify that you want to center `all_predictors() & all_numeric()` like this:

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.2 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.3      ✓ recipes   0.1.15
#> ✓ dials     0.0.9      ✓ rsample   0.0.8 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.3      ✓ tibble    3.0.5 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.3      ✓ tidyr     1.1.2 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.4      ✓ tune      0.1.2 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.1.0      ✓ workflows 0.2.1 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.5      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()
library(dplyr)

real_estate_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~re_id, ~price_per_sqm_huf_mil, ~district, ~num_room,
  "30876343",      0.534722222222222,        1,         3,
  "31914489",      0.476119402985075,        1,         1,
  "30972289",      0.507352941176471,        1,         2,
  "31739730",      0.472972972972973,        1,         3,
  "31783137",                0.49875,        2,         3,
  "31809435",      0.439705882352941,        2,         2,
  "31943408",      0.469117647058824,        2,         3,
  "31944348",       0.56231884057971,        2,         1,
  "31961146",      0.472972972972973,        3,         3,
  "24314388",      0.649550561797753,        3,         2,
  "29840270",      0.719178082191781,        3,         3,
  "29840429",      0.719178082191781,        3,         3,
  "30873484",      0.822857142857143,        4,         3,
  "30969673",      0.533802816901408,        4,         3,
  "31333120",      0.741511627906977,        4,         3,
  "31788730",      0.527142857142857,        4,         2,
  "31948441",      0.734848484848485,        5,         2,
  "31962350",                    0.8,        5,         3,
  "31962779",      0.670454545454545,        5,         3,
  "31979128",      0.689054054054054,        5,         1
) %>%
  mutate(district = factor(district))


set.seed(123)
re_split <- initial_split(real_estate_data)
re_train <- training(re_split)
re_test  <- testing(re_split)

re_rec <- recipe(re_train,
                 formula = price_per_sqm_huf_mil ~ .) %>%
  update_role(re_id, new_role = "ID") %>%
  step_center(all_predictors() & all_numeric()) %>%
  step_scale(all_predictors() & all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(district) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors())

summary(re_rec)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   variable              type    role      source  
#>   <chr>                 <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   
#> 1 re_id                 nominal ID        original
#> 2 district              nominal predictor original
#> 3 num_room              numeric predictor original
#> 4 price_per_sqm_huf_mil numeric outcome   original

lr_model <-
  linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm")

re_wflow <-
  workflow() %>%
  add_model(lr_model) %>%
  add_recipe(re_rec)

re_fit <-
  re_wflow %>%
  fit(data = re_train)

predict(re_fit, new_data = re_test)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   .pred
#>   <dbl>
#> 1 0.486
#> 2 0.611
#> 3 0.688
#> 4 0.688
#> 5 0.768
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This has tripped up more folks than you so we are working on adding a [new set of selectors](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/pull/634) that will be merged in soon. The other option to think about, if you really do want to try transforming an outcome, is to [look into using `skip = TRUE`](https://www.tmwr.org/recipes.html#skip-equals-true).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! In hindsight makes a lot of sense :)