# Can't update role of mutated variables

Tags: tidymodels, r-recipes

## Background

I'm using the R package `{recipes}` for data preprocessing. Assume that I would like to transform some variable and then declare the transformed variable as the outcome variable for modeling.

## Problem and minimal example:

However, an error is thrown:

```r
library(tidymodels)
rec <- recipe( ~ ., data = mtcars) |> 
  step_mutate(mpg2 = mpg * 2) |> 
  update_role(mpg2, new_role = "outcome")
#> Error in `update_role()`:
#> ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#> ✖ Column `mpg2` doesn't exist.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## What I've tried

The help pages of `step_mutate()` and `update_role()` do not mention the case of updating the role of an mutated variables. When I update the role of a variable without having mutated it, no error is thrown.

There are SO questions around with a similar error message (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974520/tidymodels-problem-performing-pcr-error-cant-subset-columns-that-dont-exist), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008228/tidymodels-tune-grid-cant-subset-columns-that-dont-exist-when-not-using-for), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333419/error-on-running-predict-in-tidymodels-error-in-dplyrselect-cant-su)), but those questions seem to tap into different aspects.

## Sessioninfo

````
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Big Sur ... 10.16
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] yardstick_1.1.0    workflowsets_1.0.0 workflows_1.1.2    tune_1.0.1        
#>  [5] tidyr_1.2.1        tibble_3.1.8       rsample_1.1.1      recipes_1.0.4     
#>  [9] purrr_1.0.1        parsnip_1.0.3      modeldata_1.0.1    infer_1.0.4       
#> [13] ggplot2_3.4.0      dplyr_1.0.10       dials_1.1.0        scales_1.2.1      
#> [17] broom_1.0.2        tidymodels_1.0.0  
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] foreach_1.5.2       splines_4.2.1       R.utils_2.12.2     
#>  [4] prodlim_2019.11.13  assertthat_0.2.1    highr_0.10         
#>  [7] GPfit_1.0-8         yaml_2.3.6          globals_0.16.2     
#> [10] ipred_0.9-13        pillar_1.8.1        backports_1.4.1    
#> [13] lattice_0.20-45     glue_1.6.2          digest_0.6.31      
#> [16] hardhat_1.2.0       colorspace_2.0-3    htmltools_0.5.4    
#> [19] Matrix_1.5-3        R.oo_1.25.0         timeDate_4022.108  
#> [22] pkgconfig_2.0.3     lhs_1.1.6           DiceDesign_1.9     
#> [25] listenv_0.9.0       gower_1.0.1         lava_1.7.1         
#> [28] timechange_0.2.0    styler_1.8.1        generics_0.1.3     
#> [31] ellipsis_0.3.2      furrr_0.3.1         withr_2.5.0        
#> [34] nnet_7.3-18         cli_3.6.0           survival_3.5-0     
#> [37] magrittr_2.0.3      evaluate_0.19       R.methodsS3_1.8.2  
#> [40] fs_1.5.2            fansi_1.0.3         future_1.30.0      
#> [43] parallelly_1.34.0   R.cache_0.16.0      MASS_7.3-58.1      
#> [46] class_7.3-20        tools_4.2.1         lifecycle_1.0.3    
#> [49] stringr_1.5.0       munsell_0.5.0       reprex_2.0.2       
#> [52] compiler_4.2.1      rlang_1.0.6         grid_4.2.1         
#> [55] iterators_1.0.14    rstudioapi_0.14     rmarkdown_2.19     
#> [58] gtable_0.3.1        codetools_0.2-18    DBI_1.1.3          
#> [61] R6_2.5.1            lubridate_1.9.0     knitr_1.41         
#> [64] fastmap_1.1.0       future.apply_1.10.0 utf8_1.2.2         
#> [67] stringi_1.7.12      parallel_4.2.1      Rcpp_1.0.9         
#> [70] vctrs_0.5.1         rpart_4.1.19        tidyselect_1.2.0   
#> [73] xfun_0.36
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is currently not properly documented.

The reason why you are having problems is because `add_role()`, `update_role()` and `remove_role()` can only be applied to the variables passed to `recipe()`, and they are all executed before the step functions.

This means that the following two snippets of code returns the same result

```r
recipe( ~ ., data = mtcars) |> 
  step_mutate(mpg2 = mpg * 2) |> 
  update_role(mpg2, new_role = "outcome")

recipe( ~ ., data = mtcars) |>
  update_role(mpg2, new_role = "outcome") |>
  step_mutate(mpg2 = mpg * 2)
```

Reference here https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/blob/ab2405a0393bba06d9d7a52b4dbba6659a6dfcbd/R/roles.R#L132 :

> Roles can only be changed on the original data supplied to `recipe()`

More talk here https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/437.

The `role` argument of `step_mutate()` allows you to specify the role of the variables it creates

```r
library(recipes)

recipe( ~ ., data = mtcars) |> 
  step_mutate(mpg2 = mpg * 2, role = "outcome") |>
  prep() |>
  summary()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    variable type      role      source  
#>    <chr>    <list>    <chr>     <chr>   
#>  1 mpg      <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  2 cyl      <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  3 disp     <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  4 hp       <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  5 drat     <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  6 wt       <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  7 qsec     <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  8 vs       <chr [2]> predictor original
#>  9 am       <chr [2]> predictor original
#> 10 gear     <chr [2]> predictor original
#> 11 carb     <chr [2]> predictor original
#> 12 mpg2     <chr [2]> outcome   derived
```

Additionally, it is not recommended that you try to create/modify the outcome inside a recipe. Such modifications should happen before, preferable before data splitting.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Maybe `step_mutate()` should have as default `new_role = "other"`, if the variable is not on the recipe? I doubt that anyone would create a new variable in a recipe without intending to add it to the recipe (hence the default should reflect this). Again, thanks for all the great work in tidymodels!